# Is MSDN / Azure Active Directory information available in different formats?

Tags: documentation, microsoft, azure, msdn, active-directory

I'd like to read the documentation of Azure Active Directory on my kindle (or similar device), but don't want to use "Print to Kindle" for each and every page.

Is the Microsoft documentation for this technology available in other formats?  (.chm, PDF, etc).

If an alternative format is available, then I can adapt that to my needs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj673460.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some information in e-book format (English and other languages) located here:

[E-Book Gallery for Microsoft Technologies](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11608.e-book-gallery-for-microsoft-technologies.aspx)

*Download content for ASP.NET, Office, SQL Server, Windows Azure, SharePoint Server and other Microsoft technologies in e-book formats. Reference, guide, and step-by-step information are all available. All the e-books are free. New books will be posted as they become available.*

Not sure the all information you were looking for is here. It also appears that it's necessary to create a profile to download books.

I am a Microsoft employee and write developer documentation for the MSDN site, we don't republish all our online documentation in e-book formats. MSDN is trying to use a continuous publishing model for online content and encourages users to go online to get the latest content. To my knowledge very little of the content for developers is being published in e-book format.

Comment: Hmm, I wish it was possible for me to read up on the API while I'm on the train, etc. where no cellular connection is possible

Comment: That's a very good point. I like to read the docs on my Surface RT too but can't away from WiFi access.  There's a lot of discussion right now about how much demand there would be actually be for ubiquitous mobile access to MSDN technical documentation. I'll ask around to see if there's a favorite work-around for reading MSDN docs offline on a Kindle.

Comment: I also have an Android phone for train use, and an OSX/Windows laptop when flying...

Comment: See the link in my corrected answer.  Hope some of this is useful to you.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried to reward this answer with a bounty, but I have to wait 24 hours.  I'll try again on Monday